# Lost fform design view in MS express 2010

Tags: c++

Working on a windows forms project in MS C++ express 2010. It builds fully with no errors, runs correctly as a forms based application but in the solution explorer the icon for form1.h shows it as a header file - with the h icon, rather than with the form icon. The only answer I can come up with is I've changed/deleted something while trying to solve another problem - but what - I need to add more buttons!

Answer (score 0):

ymptom - no form icon next to .h file in solution explorer even though Express had created the file.

Somewhere, some how, I must have clicked on come setting/option/switch/something that caused Express to change the catagory fo the file.

The fix was found by looking in the vcxproj file. For somereason the following code was

```
<ClInclude Include="Form1.h" />
```

rather than

```
<ClInclude Include="Form1.h">
  <FileType>CppForm</FileType>
</ClInclude>
```

How that change happened is a mystery! any suggestions of what caused that would be much appreciated!